# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int in sql server 2008 new

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am getting this error when I am running this query.

I know this is not right but I did, and I just want to am justified answer about it.

Why this error is coming when we are running this below code.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE ( id INT, Name VARCHAR(5) );

INSERT INTO @tbl
        SELECT 1 AS Id, 142 AS Alphabets
        UNION
        SELECT 2, 'XYZ'
        UNION 
        SELECT 2, 'ABC'
        SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

> Getting error 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int'

Comment: `i am getting this error` - What error?

Answer (score 2):

the problem is 142.
When you write like this 142,
SQL think this *union* table at second column contain a INT.
you have to write like this '142'

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT, Name VARCHAR(5));

INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 1 AS Id, '142' AS Alphabets
UNION
SELECT 2, 'XYZ'
UNION 
SELECT 2, 'ABC'

SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

Comment: check my answer approved

Answer (score 0):

In **UNION** operator : number,order and data type of columns must be same in all queries.

Refer this link for more info : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms180026.aspx

Here in your query, data type of 2nd column of 1st select query is different from other union select queries 2nd column.

Thats why you must have got conversion failed  error when converting the varchar value to data type int.